# How to get a binary data in feathers services?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, upload, feathersjs

I try send a binary file with jquery to node js.

This is my jquery code:

```
$('#addLabel').click(function(){

$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3030/label/66806",
        type: 'PUT',
        data: files,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        dataType: 'binary',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("sent file");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("error " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
});

var files;

$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

function prepareUpload(event)
{
  files = event.target.files;

}
```

For example I need only show in console a data like below:

```
update(id, data, params) {

  console.log(data);

  return Promise.resolve(data);

}
```

Firebug show me that a data was sent but node show me only {}. Sent data are empty. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you add the `bodyParser.raw` middleware to parse the content type you are giving?

Comment: I tried to use the services, not middleware so I not added a bodyParser.raw. When I want to delete a file I use Ajax Type: DELETE and this file is removed and in this way I want to use PUT Ajax type that a file upload / files too. Now I use a multer and works well, but I would to use services. Is it possible in my case?

Comment: For me the data was in key of context.data, moreover I was not able to get full file there in the data.